# Ruby: detect duplication in a hash based on the combination of two key's values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have the following hash. I want to detect the hashes with same from and to value combination. Is there any way to do this efficiently in ruby ?

`attributes = {"0"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3"},  "1"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"zzz", "value"=>"3.5"}, "2"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3.5"}}`

Here attributes["2"] is a duplication of attributes["0"] ( because they have same from and to values). I want to detect this and raise an exception. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Comment: This hash is from a form, i would like to flash an error msg to user if he enters duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as below :

```
attributes = {"0"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"zzz", "value"=>"3.5"}, "2"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3.5"}}
bol = attributes.group_by{|_,v| v.values_at("from","value") }.any?{|_,v| v.size >= 2 }
raise "exception" if bol
```

Comment: Thank u so much ..:) I need from and to value combination so this line will be: `bol = attributes.group_by{|_,v| v.values_at("from","to") }.any?{|_,v| v.size >= 2 }`

Comment: @sudo-stupid Typo on my eyes.. Any way what I wrote is the suggestion or trick, you may use. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the code:

```
# => {"0"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3"}, "1"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"zzz", "value"=>"3.5"}, "2"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3.5"}}

attributes.each do|k,a|
  sel = attributes.select {|_,b| b['from'] == a['from'] && b['to'] == a['to'] }
  p sel
  raise Exception if sel.size > 1
end

# {"0"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3"}, "2"=>{"from"=>"xxx", "to"=>"yyy", "value"=>"3.5"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
> valid = h.to_a.uniq {|a| [a.last['from'], a.last['to']] }.length == h.keys.length
=> false

raise 'hash is not unique' unless valid
```